# How to show "No Results" without lag on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, keyup

I'm trying to make a simple thing to work but I can't do it without a "dirty" solution. It's laggy and I'm 100% sure not "professionally" done.

What I'd like is as simple as "No Results" showing table row if there are no results found.

---

That's how "dirty" solution works:

1. First, we open the page and see this view.
   [image]
2. To start the search (and fire the `keyup` event), let's write something that has no results in one of these tabs. Try "cr".
   [image]
3. Ok, that we have in the previous image is one result in the first tab. I've tried to do this "professionally" but I only achieved current tab perfect functionality, however, when the user types something, at the same time, others tab should react also.

   Let's open other tabs and see what we have.
   [image]
4. And the last one:
   [image]

Yep, it's working perfectly. But you don't see one thing in these images. When the user clicks on one of these tabs, the "No Results" row lags. Check this video: https://youtu.be/oevRwdsqgzg.

---

How could I do it without "lagging No Results" table row or "professionally"?
The code to codepen can be found here: https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/VQaNoP.

Or Stacksnippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("html").removeClass("no-js");
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeActivate: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#search").keyup();
      }, 0);
    }
  });
  var users = [
      "ESL_SC2",
      "OgamingSC2",
      "cretetion",
      "freecodecamp",
      "storbeck",
      "habathcx",
      "RobotCaleb",
      "noobs2ninjas",
      "mhayia"
    ],
    index,
    ajaxDone,
    userResults = [],
    $search = $("#search"),
    keyCode;

  var getUserResults = function(callback) {
    var requests1 = users.map(function(user) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/" + user,
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    });

    $.when
      .apply(null, requests1)
      .done(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          var response = arguments[i];

          var user = response[0];

          userResults[i] = {
            name: user.display_name
          };
        }

        callback();
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert(
          "User request failed. Please contact by email n3olukas@gmail.com or try again."
        );
      });
  };

  getUserResults(function() {
    var requests2 = users.map(function(user) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + user,
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    });

    $.when
      .apply(null, requests2)
      .done(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          var response = arguments[i];

          var stream = response[0];

          if (stream.stream !== null) {
            userResults[i].status =
              stream.stream.channel !== undefined ? "Online" : "";
            userResults[i].title =
              stream.stream.channel !== undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.status != undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.status :
              "" :
              "";
            userResults[i].url =
              stream.stream.channel !== undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.url !== undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.url :
              "" :
              "";
          }

          if (userResults[i].name) {
            $("#tabs-1 table").append(
              '<tr><td><a href="https://twitch.tv/' +
              userResults[i].name +
              '">' +
              userResults[i].name +
              "</a></td><td>" +
              (userResults[i].status ? "Online" : "Offline") +
              "</td><td>" +
              (userResults[i].title ? userResults[i].title : "") +
              "</td></tr>"
            );

            if (userResults[i].status && userResults[i].title) {
              $("#tabs-2 table").append(
                '<tr><td><a href="https://twitch.tv/' +
                userResults[i].name +
                '">' +
                userResults[i].name +
                "</a></td><td>Online</td><td>" +
                (userResults[i].title ? userResults[i].title : "") +
                "</td></tr>"
              );
            }

            if (!userResults[i].status) {
              $("#tabs-3 table").append(
                '<tr><td><a href="https://twitch.tv/' +
                userResults[i].name +
                '">' +
                userResults[i].name +
                "</a></td><td>Offline</td></tr>"
              );
            }
          }
        }

        if (!$("#tabs-3 tr:not(:first-child)").length) {
          $("#tabs-3 table").append(
            '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="2">No Results</td></tr>'
          );
        }

        $("body").addClass("loaded");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert(
          "Stream request failed. Please contact by email n3olukas@gmail.com or try again."
        );
      });
  });

  $("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    var val = $(this)
      .val()
      .toLowerCase();

    $("#tabs tr:not(:first-child)").hide();
    $("#tabs .no-results").remove();
    $("#tabs tr:not(:first-child)").each(function(i) {
      var text = $(this)
        .text()
        .toLowerCase();

      if (text.indexOf(val) != -1) {
        $(this).show();
      }

      if ($('#tabs tr:not(:first-child)').length - 1 == i) {
        $('tr').not(':hidden').css('border-top', 'none');
      }
    });

    if (!$("#tabs-1 tr:not(:first-child):visible").length &&
      $("#tabs-1").is(":visible")
    ) {
      $("#tabs-1 table").append(
        '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="3">No Results</td></tr>'
      );
    }

    if (!$("#tabs-2 tr:not(:first-child):visible").length &&
      $("#tabs-2").is(":visible")
    ) {
      $("#tabs-2 table").append(
        '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="3">No Results</td></tr>'
      );
    }

    if (!$("#tabs-3 tr:not(:first-child):visible").length &&
      $("#tabs-3").is(":visible")
    ) {
      $("#tabs-3 table").append(
        '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="2">No Results</td></tr>'
      );
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url("https://images8.alphacoders.com/702/702959.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#tabs ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs ul a {
  background-color: #f44336;
  width: 33.33%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 10px 0;
  float: left;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.125rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #4f5b66;
  padding: 0 .9375rem;
}

.three-dots {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

tr {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color: #673ab7;
  border: none;
}

tr:nth-child(2),
.no-results {
  border-top: none;
}

td:last-child {
  width: 50%;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 35%;
}

td:nth-child(2):not(:last-child) {
  width: 15%;
}

table td {
  padding: 0.625rem 5px;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.ui-state-active a {
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

table a:before,
footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

table a:hover:before,
footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.search-results {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1.5625rem 0;
  border-left: 0.3125rem solid #0ebeff;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.search-results h4,
.search-results p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-results a:before {
  background-color: #0ebeff;
}

.twitchtv-container {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}


/* Screen loader */

#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9.375rem;
  height: 9.375rem;
  margin: -4.6875rem 0 0 -4.6875rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  z-index: 1001;
}

#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  right: 0.3125rem;
  bottom: 0.3125rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f7d130;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9375rem;
  left: 0.9375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  bottom: 0.9375rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #0fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper,
.loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000428;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}


/* Loading animation */


/* Loading animation */

@keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.59375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

.lds-eclipse {
  -webkit-animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-shadow: 0.08rem 0 0 #0ebeff;
}

@media (max-width: 71.875em) {
  .twitchtv-container {
    width: 65%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .twitchtv-container {
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 25em) {
  .twitchtv-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader">
  </div>

  <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="twitchtv-container text-center">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Online</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Offline</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <div class="overflow-x-auto">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>User</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Title</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: is the tiny flickering the "lag" you are talking about? Well it's really tiny, and i don't think it depends on the way you test empty results, but more on the `tr` appending itself. Probably adding a `min-height` to the dropdown with same background color would fix this (if you intend to show a "No Results" row, your dropdown will always have 1 row height)

Comment: I'll try a `min-height` trick.

Comment: No, it has no effect.

Comment: Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution i talked about in comments (min-height trick) is hardly feasible with your html structure, as in my tests it's not enought to set a min-height to the table if it has no extra row inside. Might have been too many CSS rules to change, or a dummy row to add.

However, the same trick can be achieved in the Javascript part. So the flickering here was probably due to the fact that `$("#search").keyup();` is triggered on each tab change, and that inside this function, you systematically remove the "No Results" from the table even if the situation didn't change.

One solution (there may be others on the same principle) is to not remove the row each time at the start of the function, but conditionnally after the results. It seems to work fine here, not easy to see because the flickering was really tiny on my computer. Changes have a comment before them.

```js
$(function() {
  $("html").removeClass("no-js");
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeActivate: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#search").keyup();
      }, 0);
    }
  });
  var users = [
      "ESL_SC2",
      "OgamingSC2",
      "cretetion",
      "freecodecamp",
      "storbeck",
      "habathcx",
      "RobotCaleb",
      "noobs2ninjas",
      "mhayia"
    ],
    index,
    ajaxDone,
    userResults = [],
    $search = $("#search"),
    keyCode;

  var getUserResults = function(callback) {
    var requests1 = users.map(function(user) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/" + user,
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    });

    $.when
      .apply(null, requests1)
      .done(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          var response = arguments[i];

          var user = response[0];

          userResults[i] = {
            name: user.display_name
          };
        }

        callback();
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert(
          "User request failed. Please contact by email n3olukas@gmail.com or try again."
        );
      });
  };

  getUserResults(function() {
    var requests2 = users.map(function(user) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + user,
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    });

    $.when
      .apply(null, requests2)
      .done(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          var response = arguments[i];

          var stream = response[0];

          if (stream.stream !== null) {
            userResults[i].status =
              stream.stream.channel !== undefined ? "Online" : "";
            userResults[i].title =
              stream.stream.channel !== undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.status != undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.status :
              "" :
              "";
            userResults[i].url =
              stream.stream.channel !== undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.url !== undefined ?
              stream.stream.channel.url :
              "" :
              "";
          }

          if (userResults[i].name) {
            $("#tabs-1 table").append(
              '<tr><td><a href="https://twitch.tv/' +
              userResults[i].name +
              '">' +
              userResults[i].name +
              "</a></td><td>" +
              (userResults[i].status ? "Online" : "Offline") +
              "</td><td>" +
              (userResults[i].title ? userResults[i].title : "") +
              "</td></tr>"
            );

            if (userResults[i].status && userResults[i].title) {
              $("#tabs-2 table").append(
                '<tr><td><a href="https://twitch.tv/' +
                userResults[i].name +
                '">' +
                userResults[i].name +
                "</a></td><td>Online</td><td>" +
                (userResults[i].title ? userResults[i].title : "") +
                "</td></tr>"
              );
            }

            if (!userResults[i].status) {
              $("#tabs-3 table").append(
                '<tr><td><a href="https://twitch.tv/' +
                userResults[i].name +
                '">' +
                userResults[i].name +
                "</a></td><td>Offline</td></tr>"
              );
            }
          }
        }

        if (!$("#tabs-3 tr:not(:first-child)").length) {
          //test if it exists before appending
          if(!$("#tabs-3 .no-results").length){
            $("#tabs-3 table").append(
              '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="2">No Results</td></tr>'
            );
          }
        }

        $("body").addClass("loaded");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert(
          "Stream request failed. Please contact by email n3olukas@gmail.com or try again."
        );
      });
  });

  $("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    var val = $(this)
      .val()
      .toLowerCase();

    $("#tabs tr:not(:first-child)").hide();
    //$("#tabs .no-results").remove(); //leave the rows for the moment
    $("#tabs tr:not(:first-child)").each(function(i) {
      var text = $(this)
        .text()
        .toLowerCase();

      if (text.indexOf(val) != -1) {
        $(this).show();
      }

      if ($('#tabs tr:not(:first-child)').length - 1 == i) {
        $('tr').not(':hidden').css('border-top', 'none');
      }
    });

    if (!$("#tabs-1 tr:not(:first-child):visible").length &&
      $("#tabs-1").is(":visible")
    ) {
      //test if it exists before appending
      if(!$("#tabs-1 .no-results").length){
        $("#tabs-1 table").append(
          '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="3">No Results</td></tr>'
        );
      }
    }else{
      //test if it exists before removing
      if($("#tabs-1 .no-results").length){
        $("#tabs-1 .no-results").remove();
      }
    }

    if (!$("#tabs-2 tr:not(:first-child):visible").length &&
      $("#tabs-2").is(":visible")
    ) {
      //test if it exists before appending
      if(!$("#tabs-2 .no-results").length){
        $("#tabs-2 table").append(
          '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="3">No Results</td></tr>'
        );
      }
    }else{
      //test if it exists before removing
      if($("#tabs-2 .no-results").length){
        $("#tabs-2 .no-results").remove();
      }
    }

    if (!$("#tabs-3 tr:not(:first-child):visible").length &&
      $("#tabs-3").is(":visible")
    ) {
      //test if it exists before appending
      if(!$("#tabs-3 .no-results").length){
        $("#tabs-3 table").append(
          '<tr class="no-results"><td colspan="2">No Results</td></tr>'
        );
      }
    }else{
      //test if it exists before removing
      if($("#tabs-3 .no-results").length){
        $("#tabs-3 .no-results").remove();
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url("https://images8.alphacoders.com/702/702959.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#tabs ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs ul a {
  background-color: #f44336;
  width: 33.33%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 10px 0;
  float: left;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.125rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #4f5b66;
  padding: 0 .9375rem;
}

.three-dots {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

tr {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color: #673ab7;
  border: none;
}

tr:nth-child(2),
.no-results {
  border-top: none;
}

td:last-child {
  width: 50%;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 35%;
}

td:nth-child(2):not(:last-child) {
  width: 15%;
}

table td {
  padding: 0.625rem 5px;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.ui-state-active a {
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

table a:before,
footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

table a:hover:before,
footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.search-results {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1.5625rem 0;
  border-left: 0.3125rem solid #0ebeff;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.search-results h4,
.search-results p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-results a:before {
  background-color: #0ebeff;
}

.twitchtv-container {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}


/* Screen loader */

#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9.375rem;
  height: 9.375rem;
  margin: -4.6875rem 0 0 -4.6875rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  z-index: 1001;
}

#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  right: 0.3125rem;
  bottom: 0.3125rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f7d130;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9375rem;
  left: 0.9375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  bottom: 0.9375rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #0fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper,
.loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000428;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}


/* Loading animation */


/* Loading animation */

@keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.59375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

.lds-eclipse {
  -webkit-animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-shadow: 0.08rem 0 0 #0ebeff;
}

@media (max-width: 71.875em) {
  .twitchtv-container {
    width: 65%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .twitchtv-container {
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 25em) {
  .twitchtv-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader">
  </div>

  <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="twitchtv-container text-center">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Online</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Offline</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <div class="overflow-x-auto">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>User</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Title</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same flickering. I don't know what's wrong here, maybe because Chrome can't handle JS code so quickly. I'll try with another browser.

Comment: Same with Mozilla Firefox. I don't know.. :)

Comment: i'll take a look if i have time, there may still be parts that clears the content. If not, this could be jQuery tab's cause for an obscure reason, the fact is that only this tab seems impacted..